# it is necessary to check params in url using node express?

Tags: node.js, rest, security, express

I have some rest endpoint, like this:

```
router.get('/groups/leave/:hash', (req, res) => {
    if (!req.params.hash) {
        return res.send({ res: false, code: responseCode.PARAMS_MISS })
    }
    console.log(req.params.hash)
})
```

User can go `localhost:8080/groups/leave/somecode`, when use go to `localhost:8080/groups/leave/` he get 404 - page not exist.

So my question is, it is necessary (for security reason - hash can be undefined) to check if is not undefined?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define two end points for this one for this (localhost:8080/groups/leave/) and one for (localhost:8080/groups/leave/:hash) or check if there is params redirects to params page and if not give a message params not defined or redirect to page where params not r.In this way if there is no params it will redirect to first one and if there is params it will redirect to hash one.And for your question YES it is better to check..you should follow code standards.Its a good practice.